# Remove Day Of Week from displayed date

Tags: datetime

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{date}{19}{09}{2016}
\date{\displaydate{date}}

\displaydate{date}
```

When I run this it show date with day like:

> Monday 19th September, 2016.

But I do not want appear the Monday. Anybody can help?

Comment: `\showdowfalse` in preamble to enable it in your whole document, or `{\showdowfalse\displaydate{date}}` for just the one time.

Comment: "{\showdowfalse\displaydate{date}}" it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You'll achieve this by using `nodayofweek` argument for you date presentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}
\newcommand{\mydate}{\formatdate{19}{09}{2016}}

\begin{document}
    \mydate
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Consider migrating from the now-obsolete [`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime) to [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB,showdow=false]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}

\DTMsavedate{date}{2016-09-19}

\begin{document}

\DTMusedate{date}

\end{document}
```

The key here is to remove the `d`ay `o`f the `w`eek from the formatting via `showdow=false`.